# Basic question regarding before and after intervention analysis on groups of different sample size

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paired-data, independence, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Apologies for the basic nature of this question. I have collected data before and after an intervention and assessed response to the intervention using a survey. This was a basic survey using a 1-5 scoring system before and after the intervention.

I received 9 survey responses prior to the intervention and 5 responses after the intervention. I am trying to compare the scores before and after. What would be the best test to assess this?

Thanks in advance